# Array Insert database with file upload loop in laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

View code

```
@foreach($questions as $question)
<input type="hidden" name="question[{{$question->id}}]" value="{{$question->id}}">
<textarea name="answers[{{$question->id}}]"></textarea>
<input type="file" name="answerfile[{{$question->id}}]">
@endforeach
```

Controller Code for update data and file upload

```
public function finishExam(Request $request)
{
foreach ( $request->get('question') as  $key => $answer) {
     $answers[] = [
         'quiz_id' => $quiz->id,
         'user_id' => $user_record->id,
         'written_question_id' => $answer->question,
         'answers' =>  $request->get('answers')[$key],
         'answerfile' =>  $request->file('answerfile')[$key],
         ];
    }
    this->validate($request, [

        'answerfile' => 'required',
        'answerfile.*' => 'mimes:doc,pdf,docx,zip'

    ]);
        foreach($request->file('answerfile') as $file)
        {
            if($request->hasfile('answerfile'))
            {
            $name=$file->getClientOriginalName();
            $file->move(public_path().'/uploads/written/', $name);
            $data[$answer] = $name;
        }
    }
    $file->answerfile=json_encode($data);
    $file->save();
WrittenResult::insert($answers);
}
```

Answers are inserting right way but files are not uploading as row by row. If upload all file of the loop then it work but insert in one row and if blank any one file then it will not work properly.
Please help me on inserting data and file in row by row.
Feel free to share another idea.

Comment: Can you show a dd($answers), before you insert please.

Comment: array:1 [▼
  0 => array:9 [▼
    "quiz_id" => 2
    "user_id" => 12
    "written_question_id" => "4"
    "answers" => ""
    "answerfile" => UploadedFile {#779 ▼
      
    }
  ]
]

Comment: #779 ▼
-test: false
      -originalName: "27863-Amphan-Relief--2.docx"
      -mimeType: "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document"
      -size: 13004
      -error: 0
      #hashName: null
      path: "E:\xampp\tmp"
      filename: "phpF130.tmp"
      basename: "phpF130.tmp"
      pathname: "E:\xampp\tmp\phpF130.tmp"
      extension: "tmp"
      realPath: false
      writable: false
      readable: false
      executable: false
      file: false
      dir: false
      link: false

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to try this.

```
    foreach ($request->get('question') as $key => $answer) {
        $answers[] = [
            'quiz_id' => $quiz->id,
            'user_id' => $user_record->id,
            'written_question_id' => $answer->question,
            'answers' => $request->get('answers')[$key],
            'answerfile' => $request->file('answerfile')[$key],
        ];
    }
    $this->validate($request, [

        'answerfile' => 'required',
        'answerfile.*' => 'mimes:doc,pdf,docx,zip'
    ]);

    if ($request->hasfile('answerfile')[$key]) {
        $file = $request->file('answerfile')[$key];
        $name = $file->getClientOriginalName();
        $file->move(public_path() . '/uploads/written/', $name);
        $data[$answer] = $name;
    }else{
        $data[$answer]="no_img.png";
    }
```

I hope it's working for you.

Comment: Also I need to put files, I can save in database as these name but How can I handle these files to upload my server? 
  <input type="file" name="answerfile[{{$question->id}}]" class="form-control" multiple>
do you have nay solution?

Comment: You can save only file name in database and file save in one particular folder.

Comment: And if file can not upload in any row  than put dummy file in your particular folder and dummy file name in database.

Comment: can you give me a solution?

Comment: i have edited my answer,in answer you can put no_img.png in your folder (public_path() . '/uploads/written/').and check it's working or not.

Comment: Thanks but there $data[$answer] = $name;
should I change $data[] = $name; ?
or  $data[$file] = $name;

Comment: It's showing,
Undefined offset: 7
at HandleExceptions->handleError(8, 'Undefined offset: 7', 'Controller.php', 497, array('request' => object(Request),'questions' => object(Collection), 'record' => object(WrittenExams), 'filename' => 'Results.pdf,Quranic Grammar Questions.pdf', 'file' => object(UploadedFile), 'name' => 'Quranic Grammar Questions.pdf', 'allfiles' => array('Results.pdf', 'Quranic Grammar Questions.pdf'), 'answer' => '7', 'key' => 7, 'marks' => object(Collection)))in StudentWrittenController.php (line 497)

Comment: i have again edited my answer please check once and let me know it's working or not.

Comment: Thanks for Co-operation. I have solve my issues with some modification.

Answer (score 0):

I have solved my issue.Special thanks to @yagna pathak

```
foreach ( $request->get('question') as $key => $answer) {
    $name = '';
        if (isset($request->file('answerfile')[$key])) {
            $file = $request->file('answerfile')[$key];
            $name = time()."-".rand(9,999999)."-".$file->getClientOriginalName();
            $file->move(public_path() . '/uploads/written/', $name);
        }
    $answers[] = [
        'quiz_id' => $quiz->id,
        'user_id' => $user_record->id,
        'written_question_id' => $answer,
        'answers' => $request->get('answers')[$key],
        'answerfile' => $name
    ];
}
```

I want look lie this:

[image]